# SendGrid - How to remove unsubscribe link from some emails sent using Dynamic template

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I have enabled Subscription Tracking in SendGrid and set the content as HTML body. So every email sent programmatically(in Node.js) using dynamic templateId will have the unsubscribe link.

But we want one dynamic template not to attach the unsubscribe link while sending emails. The template does not have the "Unsubscribe" module but still the unsubscribe link will be present in the mails.

How to prevent one dynamic template from attaching the unsubscribe link?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding this parameter in the send email function would make it work as expected -

```
 tracking_settings: {
   subscription_tracking: {
     enable: false
   }
 }
```

Comment: What else does this do?